# Incorrect vertical alignment in IE8

Tags: css, internet-explorer-8

The default text in my search box looks fine in Chrome, FF, and Safari (vertical-align: middle).

However, the **default text rises to the top of the search box in IE 8**.

Is there a workaround for IE? Thanks for your help.

**HTML:**

```
<input type="text" class="text" value="Search" title="Search" />
```

**CSS:**

```
.text {
    height: 47px;
    font-size: 18px;
    margin: 0; 
    padding: 0 5px 0 45px;
}
```

Answer (score 88, accepted):

Have you tried setting the line height to match the height of the text box? The text should automatically appear in the middle of the line

Comment: YOU ARE A KING! i have wasted around 5 hours with this problem. Thanks

Comment: Excellent cross-browser friendly solution. I really didn't want to find another `padding-top` solution. +1

Comment: In Chrome/Safari (at least on Mac) setting a `line-height` of something big like `50px` means that you have a blinking cursor that is 50px tall, which looks a little weird.

Comment: Hi, What about inside a "a" tag?? it is not working inside a "a" tag

Comment: @Dhanil it should still work within an `<a/>` tag, though I wouldn't usually have an input within an anchor. I suggest you raise a new question and include your markup as this answer is over 5 years old now.

Comment: @inbob No no am talking about pure <a> tag, not inside input. Issue in IE only

Comment: line-height doesnt really work if you actually have more than one line :(

Answer (score 3):

Specifying line-height causes the cursor to grow very tall in Chrome , i will suggest to use equal padding from top/bottom to vertically align text in IE8, it will work in Chrome/FF/IE8