# HTML textbox doesn't set vertical alignment in IE

Tags: html, internet-explorer, text, textbox

```
<html>
<body>
<input type="text" style="height:200px;vertical-align:middle">
</body>
</html>
```

The above HTML renders textbox with middle vertical align in Chrome/FF, but it is showing at top align only in IE. How to make the text middle aligned for IE?

Comment: what version of ie are you using? it works in ie 9 and 10

Comment: I am using IE 8. Check by setting Compatibility and document modes to IE8

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3893256/incorrect-vertical-alignment-in-ie8

Comment: Cool... paste that line from the link as an answer, and will mark it :) thanks for the help